# Not able to use calculated value in CONCAT statement

Tags: sql, case, concatenation, divide

```
Case when sim.PickPackUom='IP' then  sim.InnerPackQuantity 
else 
   im.CaseQuantity
end 
  as divqty
,concat (cast (i.QuantityOnHand as float)/divqty  ,' ',  sim.PickPackUom  )qty
```

concat is giving error. How can I make divqty value available for concat or division?

Comment: make it part of a sub-select

Comment: which error is giving you?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the entire case condition instead of divqty:

```
Case when sim.PickPackUom='IP' then  sim.InnerPackQuantity 
    else im.CaseQuantity
    end as divqty
,concat (
       cast (i.QuantityOnHand as float)/
             (Case when sim.PickPackUom='IP' then  sim.InnerPackQuantity 
                   else im.CaseQuantity end),
       ' ',  sim.PickPackUom) qty
```